# JQuery reset value of text input when checkbox is unchecked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a fieldset in my form that has a check box tied to a text input. When the checkbox is checked/unchecked it toggles the readonly attribute of the text input.

When the checkbox is unchecked I would like the text input value to reset to 0.

Here is my

```
<label for="device-9102" class="form-partner-label"><input type="checkbox" class="quote-chkbox" id="9102-chk"> 9102 IP Phone</label>
<input type="text" name="9102-quantity" class="form-endpoint-qty form-control" id="form-partner-9102" readonly value="0">
```

Here is the JQuery that currently sets the readonly value for the text input:

```
$("#9102-chk").change(function() {
        $("#form-partner-9102").prop("readonly", !$(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

How do I reset the value of the text input to 0 when the checkbox is unchecked?

Comment: Use the [`val(value)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) function to set it to 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to check for checkbox is checked or not & then set the value to input using `.val()`

```js
$("#9102-chk").change(function() {
     var is_checked = $(this).is(":checked");
     if(!is_checked) {
      $("#form-partner-9102").val(0);
     }
     $("#form-partner-9102").prop("readonly", !is_checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="device-9102" class="form-partner-label"><input type="checkbox" class="quote-chkbox" id="9102-chk"> 9102 IP Phone</label>
<input type="text" name="9102-quantity" class="form-endpoint-qty form-control" id="form-partner-9102" readonly value="0">
```

Comment: Outstanding! Thank you!